CIDR block for a subnet within VPC
When you create a subnet, you specify the CIDR block for the subnet, which is a subset of the VPC CIDR block.
But in the below diagram:

PublicSubnet1 is being assigned a network 10.10.32.0/20(which is not a subset of 10.10.0.0/16 network of VPC)

How does a packet with network id 10.10.32.0 enter into VPC with network id 10.10.0.0? Because as per my understanding, 10.10.0.0/19 is a subnet of 10.10.0.0/16 network but 10.10.32.0/20 is not a subnet of 10.10.0.0/16 network..correct me

I find CIDRs hard to calculate in my head. It's always advisable to use a CIDR calculator (eg https://cidr.xyz/).
A CIDR of 10.10.0.0/16 goes from 10.10.0.0 to 10.10.255.254.
A CIDR of 10.10.32.0/20 goes from 10.10.32.0 to 10.10.47.255. It IS a subset of 10.10.0.0/16.

Another question....if this AWS account uses 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.254 for their VPC. Can this same AWS account be able to create another VPC using 10.x.x.x CIDR?  Am assuming, these IP ranges(10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.254) are available per AWS account, for allocating VPC's, correct me

Every VPC is independent, so you can create multiple VPCs with the same/overlapping IP address ranges. However, you cannot use VPC Peering to connect two VPCs that have overlapping IP ranges. Therefore, if you do not require the VPC to use /16 (with 65,000 addresses), it would be a good idea to use a smaller CIDR (eg /20).

ok....If multiple VPC's(within AWS account) have same/overlapping IP address, then, is it the InternetGateWay public IP that distinguish one VPC from another? for the packets coming from internet towards VPC

The Internet Gateway itself does not have an IP address. Rather, resources that need to communicate with the Internet need to be assigned a public IP address (in addition to the private IP address). When these resources communicate with the Internet, the traffic goes through the Internet Gateway, which performs reverse-NAT to make it look like the traffic is coming from the public IP address. When incoming traffic is received for a given public IP address, the Internet Gateway forwards that traffic to the private IP address of the appropriate resource. It knows which VPC to use.

So, IGW knows which VPC to forward incoming traffic?

Yes. Each Public IP address is associated with a specific resource (eg network interface on an EC2 instance). Those resources are associated with a VPC. The Internet Gateway therefore knows where to send traffic that was sent to the public IP address.
